# Server guessing game python

Tags: python

I want to write a number guessing game number(The computer guesses). Even I can not specify the interval. What should I do?for example : my number = 20 ,first server guess = 15 ,second server guess = 25 ,how can i specify (15 ,25) ?

```
import random
guess = random.randint(1, 99)
print (guess)
user = input('your opinon: ')

while user != 'correct':
    if user == 'too low!':
        guess = random.randint(guess, 99)
        print(guess)
        user = input()
    else:
        guess = random.randint(1, guess)
        print(guess)
        user = input()

if user == 'correct':
    print('wowooOooWww!! you win!!')
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres a better way to do it:

```
import random
print("mentally pick a number between 1-99")
min = 1
max = 99

while True:
    guess = random.randint(min, max)
    print(guess)
    user = input("high, low, or correct: ")
    if user.lower() == "correct":
        print("i win!")
        break
    elif user.lower() == "low":
        min = guess
    elif user.lower() == "high":
        max = guess
```